# Determine the symmetry group of the given designs

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

**Question**: for each design given in picture(attached) determine the symmetry group.

[image: click here for picture]

**My attempt**: 
For first design in first row, i think group of symmetry is $D_4$ i.e. Dihedral group of order $8$. Since first design has four rotational symmetries (rotation by $0°$, rotation by $90°$, rotation by $180°$, rotation by $270°$) and four reflection symmetries.

For second design (from left side) in first row, i think group of symmetry is cyclic rotation group of order $3$ and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$. since second design has three rotational symmetries but not reflectional  symmetries.

For third design in first row i am not sure.

For fourth design i think it is $D_{16}$. i.e Dihedral group of order $32$.

For first design in second row, i think its $D_7$ i.e Dihedral group of order $14$.

For second design in second row, i think the group of symmetry is $D_4$ i e Dihedral group of order $8$.

For third design, i think its $D_5$.

For last design, i think it is also $D_5$.

I am not sure of my answer and i dont have solution/key for this exercise. Please help.

Comment: I think the last one is $D_{10}$, the group of order $20$.

Comment: @DonThousand  sir Yes. :-)

Comment: Bottom last one? I don't think that one has reflectional symmetries, so it should be $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good attempt.

The groups, respectively, are

$$\begin{array} & & & \\
 D_4 & \Bbb Z_3 & D_3 & D_{16} \\
D_7 & D_4 & D_5 & \Bbb Z_{10},
\end{array}$$

where $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$.

Comment: Sir Can you explain how group symmetry is $D_{10}$ for fourth design in first row?

Comment: Think of the centre of each of the rectangular bits as a vertex for a regular $10$-gon, @AkashPatalwanshi.

Comment: sir , so there are $16$ vertex and hence $8$ sides. So group of symmetry must be $D_8$

Comment: I miscounted, @AkashPatalwanshi. I'm sorry. There are $16$ vertices, one each to place in the centre of the rectangular bits. Hence the group must be $D_{16}$.

Comment: sir I think its $D_8$ dihedral group of order $16$

Comment: No, @AkashPatalwanshi; $D_8$ is the symmetry group of an octagon. Don't forget the rotational symmetries as well as the reflections.

Comment: Yes sir sorry I forget $16$ vertex :-)